# Client's method description for WCF service

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF service (hosted in windows-service) and a client for it.

They interact as follows: client sends a request, service gets it and returns HTTP 200. Also client passes its address for the answer in the WS-Addressing header. For the moment that's all

After a few hours windows-service should send a result for that request. Client has a web-method that will get the result. So the question is: where should be a description (name of the method, its parameters) for the client's method that will get the result? Should the client expose its WSDL, or should I put that description in my WSDL (if it works that way)?

Comment: The client won't have a WSDL - only the service.  Are you expecting the client to stay connected for the few hours it takes for the service to send back the result?  That's not what I would consider a good design for a web service.  A lot can happen that would cause a disconnect during those few hours.  In any event, it sounds like you want a duplex binding (for callbacks to the client from the service).   Can you provide more details and code examples for your situation?

Comment: Of course client won't stay connected few hours. As I said it gets HTTP 200 and that is the end of its request. And client has its own web-methods and one of them is for getting answer from my WCF. So who should take care of description of this method, so I could call it?

Comment: So the client is itself a service as well?  As far as the client getting an answer later from the service, that should be a method exposed by the service that is called by the client.  If other clients are calling the first client, then the first client (acting as a service) could also expose a method for getting the results.  I.e., Service A does the processing.  Client A (which is also Service B) can request results from Service A.  Client A (acting as Service B) could also expose a similar method that could be used by Client C.

Comment: No, client shouldn't call WCF service for result, cause in that case he would call it repeatedly (as he doesn't know if result is ready). It's WCF service sends result as soon as it ready. Sorry, I forgot to mention that WCF is hosted in the windows service, so it is windows-service who sends the result to client.

Comment: Ah.  In that case one solution would be to have the client (again, acting as a service as well as client) have a method that the "master" service could call, so then it would be in the client's WSDL.  Service A (the Windows Service hosting WCF) does the processing based on the request from the client (again, acting as a service in its own right).  Service A would then call the client to return the results.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to clarify - it's the client who should provide the info about its method. Well, it's pretty obvious actually, but the fellow developer on the client side was insisting that I somehow should take care of description of **his** method in **my** WSDL. If he's wrong you may write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Your WSDL should know nothing about the other service.  That's part of the whole concept behind web services.  Answer posted :)

Comment: That's a relief, I thought I was going crazy )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your scenario, you have two services, let's call them Service A (hosted in a Windows Service) and Service B.   Service B sends a request to Service A (in other words, it's acting like a client) to have Service A start a long-running task of some sort.

When the task is complete, Service A needs to send the results to Service B.  Since it's a long-running task, using a duplex binding would *not* be ideal.  However, Service A could call a method exposed by Service B to send the results.

Something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceA
{

    [OperationContract]
    public void StartWork();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceB
{

    [OperationContract]
    public void ReceiveResults(ResultData data);
}
```

where `ResultData` is some object containing the results (could be a simple type as well, this is simply for illustration).   ServiceA's `StartWork` can return void (the response will still be sent to the client, since it's not marked as `IsOneWay=true`).  Semi-pseduo code follows:

Start the task:

```
ServiceAClient client = new ServiceAClient();
client.Open();
client.StartWork();
client.Close();
```

Service A sends the results to Service B when the task is complete:

```
ResultData results = new ResultData();
ServiceBClient client = new ServiceBClient();
client.Open();
client.ReceiveResults(results);
client.Close();
```

In this case, the method to receive the results will be part of *Service B's* WSDL, as Service A will call that method.

Comment: @Tim congrats on your silver WCF badge! You join an exclusive group of 12 users. Truth be told I was racing you for it ;)

Comment: @TomRedfern - Thanks -  You'll probably beat me to gold :)